# Splitting a list of strings into 2 lists, one containing single values and the other multiples

Tags: list, delphi, loops, iteration

I have a large list of strings, it's a TStringList and is sorted by key.  The structure is ('Key', Obj).
In this list there are single and repeated key values.  I'm trying to split them into two separate lists, one for the single values and one for the repeated ones.

If my initial list is {A,A,A,B,B,C,D,E,E,F} then the result should be a list of singles = {C,D,F} and a list of repeats = {A,B,E}.

I've tried many different variations of the same code to try and get it to work but I'm having problems, a lot of them. :)

I'm getting key[i] and key[i+1] and comparing them, if they're the same I save [i+1] into a temp string and set a bool value, I then run some conditional checks to determine what list it should go in but just failing at the moment.

It seems like it should be such an easy thing to accomplish and I am somewhat embarrassed to have to ask.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is the initial list always sorted?

Comment: post the code you have.

Comment: @ain, yes, the code is always sorted, thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: You don't necessarily need two separate lists.  Create one list that has one entry per unique value and a count of occurrences, e.g. NewList.AddObject('A', Pointer(3)), and iterate that, looking for single-occurrence or multi- ones.  You can, of course, regenerate your original list from NewList.

Comment: `TDictionary<string,Integer>` would get the job done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StartIndex := 0;
for i := 1 to List.Count - 1 do
  if List[i].Key <> List[StartIndex].Key then begin
    if i - StartIndex = 1 then
      SingleList.Add(List[StartIndex])
    else
      MultiList.Add(List[StartIndex])
    StartIndex := i;
  end;

//check for the last chunk
if StartIndex = List.Count - 1 then
  SingleList.Add(List[StartIndex])
else
  MultiList.Add(List[StartIndex])
```

Comment: I genuinely cannot thank you enough.  If you were here, several beers would duly be owed.  Thank you and thank you again.  On one hand I'm glad it was more complicated than I was anticipating, on the other; I should've known to do this.  Thank you again.

Comment: Excellent compact solution. Clever usage of StartIndex and diff between i and StartIndex.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the mistake you're making is that you don't select correct index for the next comparision in case `key[i] = key[i+1]`. So if input is `A,A,A,B,B` you first compare `i := 0 => [0]=[1]` (you compare first two `A`) which is True. Then you probably proceed with `i := 2` which means that you compare last `A` to the first `B` which causes the bug. Solution is to move index to the next value after last key witch equals to the current matching key, ie something like

```
while(list.Count > i)and(list.keys[i] = currentKey)do Inc(i);
```

at the appropriate place should make sure that you make next key comparision with correct list items.